# Multilevel send with variables

Tags: ruby

I have a script that pulls data from a object with lots of hashes and sub-objects.

I currently read the values through calls such as:

```
node_item.automatic[:ipaddress]
node_item.normal.network[:location]
node_item.default["motd"][:additional_text]
```

With large lists this is becoming unwieldy to maintain and I think there should be a better way to do it.

I have set up an array of hashes similar to below:

```
{
    :display_name => "Internal IP",
    :key => "automatic[:ipaddress]",
    :value => ""
},
{
    :display_name => "Location",
    :key => "normal.network[:location]",
    :value => ""
},  
{
    :display_name => "Description",
    :key => "default['motd'][:additional_text]",
    :value => ""
}
```

I have tried to use

```
node_item.send(hash[:key])
```

which doesn't work due to the symbol and hash call in there.

My last attempt was:

```
field[:key].inject(node_item){ |r, m| r.send(r); r }[field[:value]]`
```

which just throws a nice error containing the whole top-level object with the response:

```
is not a symbol (TypeError)`
```

I tried moving the variables to their own key but then I run into trouble with the multi-function calls and the multi-level hashes on some of the responses.

To make it work seems to require just as much special-case code as just calling a huge list.

I understand I can use `eval()` to possibly do this but that may have security implications if I am taking input from the command line.

Comment: I'm confused, what is `field[:key]` in your method?

Comment: Ah, sorry, field is the hash variable.
From something similar to table_field.each { |field| ... }

Comment: It is unclear what your desired output is. What is it? And what is your original hash look like?

Comment: @Zabba 
node_item is a large object which contains about 2500 variables and objects under 4 levels
eg:
node_item.XXX
node_item.manual.XXX
node_item.automatic.item.item.XXX
node_item.default.test.item.2nditem.XXX

my end goal is to get a subset of this information out in the easiest way possible for reporting.

Comment: Taking input from the command-line isn't that big an issue, it's taking input from the web, especially if your code is running with escalated privileges. If you're taking input from the command-line, odds are good the user could do bad things at the command-line without involving your code.

Comment: @Kim, you should update your question showing the input hash sample and an output result sample.